# Typescript: Reason behind Interface A incorrectly extends interface B errors

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I try extend an interface by adding more properties, it becomes non assignable to a function accepting the base interface type. Why's that? Isn't it guaranteed that overriding interface type will always have the properties present that function, accepting Base interface type, expects.

There exists a lot of questions regarding the same on StackOverflow but none of them answer why it happens or why it supposed to be like this or how to fix this error with expected outcome.

There is an open Github issue thread around same since 2017 - [TS Proposal : "Interface incorrectly extends interface" - sub-interface method overload OR override ?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20920)

Where is my understanding about extended interface is incorrect?

Please help out a newbie TS developer!!! Thanks...

```
// ------------------------ Types Declaration ----------------

interface ServerRequest {
    url: string,
    method: string,
    body: string | undefined
}

interface ExtendedServerRequest extends ServerRequest {
    orignal_url: string | undefined
}

type FunctionOrignal = (req: ServerRequest)=> void
type FunctionOverridden = (req: ExtendedServerRequest)=> void

interface ShortHandOptions {
    onSend: FunctionOrignal
}

interface ExtendedShortHandOptions extends ShortHandOptions {
    onSend: FunctionOverridden
}

// ------------------------ Test ----------------------------

console.log('------------------------------------------------');

function test(opts: ShortHandOptions) {
    opts.onSend({
        url: 'https://httpbin.org/get',
        method: 'GET'
    } as ServerRequest);
}

var func1: FunctionOrignal = (req) => {
        console.log('FunctionOrignal', req.url);
    },
    func2: FunctionOverridden = (req) => {
        console.log('FunctionOverridden', req.orignal_url);
    };

test({ onSend: func1 } as ShortHandOptions);

test({ onSend: func2 } as ExtendedShortHandOptions);
```

This results in:-

```
Interface 'ExtendedShortHandOptions' incorrectly extends interface 'ShortHandOptions'.
  Types of property 'onSend' are incompatible.
    Type 'FunctionOverridden' is not assignable to type 'FunctionOrignal'.
      Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
        Property 'orignal_url' is missing in type 'ServerRequest' but required in type 'ExtendedServerRequest'.
```

This should work as long as `test` function calls `onSend` with an argument of type `ShortHandOptions` i.e. an argument with at least the following properties { url, method, body }.

Comment: Note that "orignal" should probably be changed to "original"

Comment: This is an issue of *contravariance* of function parameters. The problem with your code can be demonstrated [in this playground link](//tsplay.dev/WkDb0w).  Admittedly it is probably rare that someone will pass an object with an `orignal_url` property that isn't either `string` or undefined, but that's the problem. You could work around it by marking the property optional (which has the same safety hole but the compiler allows it). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is almost correct.
When you type `ExtendedServerRequest` as

```
orignal_url?: string
```

instead of

```
orignal_url: string | undefined
```

everything should work as expected. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFpK6drQCoE8AOBTAzqAImgxgDYCGATkQC4CWA9gHYRyMBQTlt5aJAZkXmqAGVOAN04AlNAEcArpnKgA3k1ArQ0kgQBcoDORJsA5gBplqgLZpyAC2oATbbv21jplQCM7SB3sOgAPmq0tmhcbGi2TAC+LGwc3Lz8AKIAHhxB4UIkoiQSMnKgaKloQViZ2bmyuoquoNT6BrREBAD66gQA-N5OBlEs5Kj8AGLStHhUdADy9Y0EoAC8oAAUJFLaZeJSleQAlHMAfKDC1JQR-eigw6PjtBPZ+rbB9AvLq6ApacG26zmbcrsHRxOMXYnB4fEENhI5AAEkQghMUNcsEpVLVaEIgtpLmMaDdpk1eqwQfFwe9ip8BJCYXDbAikQUiiUIXVqfDEbjkTU6Bj7BcRjjJncTo9CSAGIwJTBEPlJbK4Cw8HQMNQCGgAHQEagGRYAcjl+oNEp12wA3CwuPzrqAOLpFtRERg1lTYWykdtqqj7eQMGrueTFijUao2todVZyOQUI6QOHI242L6SAZgAZLDqTEHzJYbLydQBxRIIHU1SKgIilEQbPK6U2E4SkUAW0YARixltxU0oDSa8yWK0k7v2HszoEVtGVqo1Wt12Oune7BHToH7aratdRkQzqibeAATG2rh2hQ9ir2XgP5gdA5mxxP1ZrtTrZ0fOPdHkuV3UuzNWhp16pIjNJgbXIAM0R5bQd2bUBS3LZkoRdWl2SVWtgLkMC-UxRt+V3GCyywMl0i+Z0aTpDlTSAA)

### Why?

For the TS compiler, there is a difference between marking a property as optional with `?` or declaring a required property that can also be `undefined` as you have done.

Since `orignal_url` may be `undefined` but is required, you cannot cast `ShortHandOptions` into `ExtendedShortHandOptions` like in your example.